# Scan integers array

Tags: c, arrays, int

First of all, I understand this may be newbie, but I'm just starting. Please, try to be patient.
I want to make a function that should sum all numbers before find number '0'.
E.g.
"1230" should return "6".
But I'm not understanding how can I scan an integer array. 
This is my code, and compiler says "Segment fault (core dumped). 
What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int sum, i, x[1000];
    printf("Insert a number");
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    sum=0;

    for (i=0; x[i]!='0'; i++)
       sum=sum+x[i];

    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be reading in a string, then iterating through the characters in that string, converting each one as you go. This also has the advantage of not being limited by the size of a c integer (32767)

Comment: the returned value from scanf (and family) should always be checked to assure the operation was successful.   However, using fgets() or getline() would get the whole input in as a character array, terminated with a newline then a '\0' .  The newline can be ignored in the code and iterate through the character array until the current character is '\0'  suggest studying how characters and integer values are stored in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'0' is a `char`, not integer. you should write `x[i]!=0`

however `char` can be auto converted to `int`, so compile OK...but '0' converts to ASCII code, so your program is equal to `x[i]!=48`

and you should check the array bounds to avoid error if 0 not exist in array. you should write `i<1000 && x[i]!=0`

EDIT: your scanf is wrong too, that scanf can only accept one number, and i wasn't assigned. I suppose you meant to scan a whole string, and just add-up digit by digit. Then you should use `char` and write like this:

```
int sum, i;
char x[1000];
scanf("%s", x);
for(int i=0; i<1000 && x[i]>'0' && x[i]<='9'; i++)
sum += (x[i] - '0');
```

Comment: It compiles but when I insert number he returns a weird huge number. I assumed printf("%d", sum) at the end of the code. What is wrong?

Comment: did u forget the `sum=0`? I just didn't write it duplicately

Comment: I did. It is working properly now. Just tell me something. (x[i] - '0') converts from ASCII to int, right?

Comment: digit characters' internal values are consecutive, so `x[i]>='0' && x[i]<='9'` ensure `x[i]` is a digit, and `x[i]-'0'` converts the digit character to integer. Since you meant to terminate at `'0'` so you should use `x[i]>'0'`

Comment: In C, `'0'` is an `int`.  Try `printf("%d\n", sizeof '0' == sizeof(char));`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to read one character at a time. If nothing else, this avoids buffer overflows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum=0, i;
    while ((i = getchar()) && i > '0' && i <= '9') sum += i - '0';
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use scanf() statement in loop.

and reason your code is giving segmentation fault is variable 'i' is uninitialized. local uninitialized variable will be containing garbage values. with 'i' having any garbage value, your program is trying to write in a memory location which outside of your user space.